# Equation var with apostrophes?

Tags: symbols, equations

Hi I want to write this:

[image]

So I wrote this:

```
$\{m'_{i}\}$
```

Without success, (I get errors/warning) 
How do I write the apostrophe in Latex?

Thanks;)

Comment: It works without errors. Can you please add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/1235) that illustrates your problem?

Comment: It seems that my file got corrupted or so... I don't know but It works now after I restored it to a past version ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use `\prime`:

```
$\{m^\prime_{i}\}$
```

`$\{m'_{i}\}$` works for me as well.

Comment: I would promote the use of `^\prime` since `'` does _exactly_ this.

Comment: @Hendrik: yes, can be read in latex.ltx where `\active@math@prime` is defined. Though similarly one could write `_\prime` and this time there's no shortcut, so it could be good to know about `\prime` and it's worth a try if `'` doesn't work as expected any more.